# How to use different size fragments on Android

Tags: android-fragments

We have a case where we pop three different fragments into a container based on user interaction. The fragments differ in height as indicated by this graphic:

[image: Diagram of our fragments]

We use `transaction.add(R.id.framelayout_main_container, frag).commit();` to add a new fragment, if `Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(frag_tags[fragNumber]);` was `null` and `transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout_main_container, frag, frag_tags[fragNumber]).commit();` when the frag was `!null`.

When viewing *Fragment 2* or *Fragment 3*, there is almost always extra space at the bottom. If the extra space is added to the height of either *Fragment 2* or *Fragment 3*, it matches the height of *Fragment 1*.

**How do we permanently get rid of the extra space in the Fragment container for the shorter fragments?**

Comment: Hi. which type of fragment container do you use? if its a framelayout it should work. I know in the old version of android (before 4.0) there was a bug with the replace function, the fragment was not being removed. so try to use remove and then add. another suggestion is to set the background of the fragment to color1 and the background of the container to color2 just to realize what causing the extra space. if you are using a viewpager, i have a code which fix that issue. let me know.

Comment: Thanks adi ohaion. We are jusing a FrameLayout as the container of our fragments. We're targeting Android 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2 (API level 14) as our minSdkVersion, so perhaps that replace function bug is there. However, the frag is almost always null, which results in the frag almost always being added instead of replaced. I'll investigate your other suggestions.

Comment: marienke it also looks like you do not set the tag in the add function. check it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int, android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String)

Comment: Which will explain why the fragment is always null!